# Make a div disapear when another toggles

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a div that appears once you click an image, it uses toggle for this. Now I also want the initial div to disappear when the second toggles, for this I used the .css function in js. The problem is it only applies to the first case, and since it receives info from the database I want this to happen in every entry. How can I apply to all?

```
<div class="div_grande">
                        <?php
                        if (!mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8")) {
                            printf("Error loading character set utf8: %s\n", mysqli_error($link));
                            exit();
                        } else {
                            $sql = "SELECT idr, nome, video, img1, img2, img3, img4, img5, img6, telefone, morada, descricao, site FROM restaurantes WHERE fk_lingua = $idl AND fk_distrito = 3";
                        }
                            $result = $conn->query($sql);

                            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                                // output data of each row
                                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                                    $id = $row['idr']; ?>
                                    <div class="conteudo_cima" id="conteudo_cima">
                                        <iframe class="img_cima" src="<?php echo $row['video']; ?>" allowfullscreen=1 frameBorder=0></iframe>
                                        <div class="texto">
                                            <h1><?php echo $row['nome']."<br>";?></h1>
                                            <?php echo $row['descricao']."<br>";?>
                                            <?php echo $row['morada']."<br>";?>
                                            <?php echo $row['telefone']."<br>";?>
                                            <a href="http://<?php echo $row['site'];?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row['site'];?></a>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="seta">
                                            <img id="trigger" src="imagens/expand.png" onclick="abreInfo(event, <?php echo $id; ?>)">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="expand" id="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                                        <div class="video">
                                             <iframe src="<?php echo $row['video']; ?>" allowfullscreen=1 frameBorder=0></iframe> 
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="galeria">
                                            <div><img src="<?= $row['img1'] ?>" ></div>
                                            <div><img src="<?= $row['img2'] ?>" ></div>
                                            <div><img src="<?= $row['img3'] ?>" ></div>
                                            <div><img src="<?= $row['img4'] ?>" ></div>
                                            <div><img src="<?= $row['img5'] ?>" ></div>
                                            <div><img src="<?= $row['img6'] ?>" ></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="fundo_expand">
                                            <div class="texto_expand">
                                                <h1><?php echo $row['nome']."<br>";?></h1>
                                                <?php echo $row['descricao']."<br>";?>
                                                <?php echo $row['morada']."<br>";?>
                                                <?php echo $row['telefone']."<br>";?>
                                                <a href="http://<?php echo $row['site'];?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $row['site']."<br><br>";?></a>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="seta_expand">
                                                <img id="trigger_expand" src="imagens/encolher.png" onclick="abreInfo(event, <?php echo $id; ?>)">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                        <?php }
                            } else {
                                echo "Sem resultados disponíveis!";
                            }
                        ?>
                    </div>

<script>
    function abreInfo(event, id){
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#"+id).toggle("slow");
    }
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#trigger").click(function(){
            $("#conteudo_cima").css("display", "none");
        });
    });
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#trigger_expand").click(function(){
            $("#conteudo_cima").css("display", "block");
        });
    });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.galeria').slick({
        dots: true,
        infinite: true,
        speed: 1000,
        autoplay:true,
        autoplaySpeed: 1200,
        arrows:true,
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1
    });
</script>

.left_corpo .bottom_left_corpo{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    height: 75%;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 1%;
}
.bottom_left_corpo .div_grande{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.div_grande .conteudo_cima{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1vw;
    position: relative;
    height: 30%;
    width: 98%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    display: block;
}
.conteudo_cima .img_cima{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 20%;
}
.conteudo_cima .texto{
    /*background-color: red;*/
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 70%;
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-top: 0;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.conteudo_cima h1{
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.conteudo_cima .seta{
    /*background-color: blue;*/
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
    margin-left: 70%;
}
.conteudo_cima .seta #trigger{
    height: 30%;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 50%;
    margin-left: 20%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expand{
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: white;
    font-size: 1vw;
    position: relative;
    width: 98%;
    margin-left: 1%;
    display: none;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.expand .video{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    display: inline-block;
}
.expand .video iframe{
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
.expand .galeria{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 40%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 15%;
}
.expand .galeria img{
    height: 200px;
    width: 80%;
    margin-left: 10%;
}
.expand .fundo_expand{
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.expand .texto_expand{
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 90%;
    margin-left: 0;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;
    overflow:hidden;
    display: inline-block;
}
.expand h1{
    font-size: 1.5vw;
    margin-top: 0;
}
.expand .seta_expand{
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 10%;
}
.expand .seta_expand #trigger_expand{
    height: 30%;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 40%;
    margin-left: 11%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

http://codepen.io/Ryuh/pen/vKYVWY

[When div closed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdKwZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Edit the click event:

```
$("#trigger").click(function(){
      $("#conteudo_cima").css("display", "none");
      //add here hiding of any other div etc...
      // i.e. 
      // $("#THE_OTHER_DIV_ID").css("display", "none");
});
```

Comment: How can I use the id on another div, since I already used the database ids?

Comment: the div you wish to hide either have an ID or a class. use it for hiding

Answer (score 0):

Don't call exactly the same function, with exactly the same id.

You need to make the function calls more specific in some way.

It's hard to tell exactly what you mean, but you could give an identifier to the div called the first time, and and identifier to the div called the second time.  Then you could make the call open and close these two different divs.

Comment: I took a different approach to close the original div. I used $("#conteudo_cima").css("display", "none"); inside the abreInfo function. Now the only problem is when closing the second div, it only works on the first one. I think I got what you are suggesting. I'll try it. Thanks